# How to stay screen On by using jquery

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins

How to stay the screen light on in cordova jquery in android .Please help me ,if there any possible way.
Thanks

Comment: yes, I want it for ever...

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin called Insomnia which prevents the screen from falling asleep:

[Insomnia Plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin)